# Javascript Date parsing error between client/server when converting from milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, milliseconds

I'm having an issue generating a Date in javascript from a specific date in milliseconds returned from a database. The data on the database is in the DateTime format 2015-08-10 00:00:00.000. This is return to the client in milliseconds. The server is running on a server in a time zone 1 hour ahead of the client.

The Date at the server in milliseconds is '1439157600000'.

On the server run locally it loses a day in UTC format but is ok in standard time.

On the remote client the UTC mirrors the server time but so does does the standard time. So the standard time is now out by -1 day with respect to the standard time on the server.

However, running the same conversion on '1420100000000', Everything works hunky dory.

For '1439157600000' we get.

Local:
Error: Sun, 09 Aug 2015 22:00:00 GMT - UTC
Error: Mon Aug 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200

Remote:
Error: Sun, 09 Aug 2015 22:00:00 GMT - UTC
Error: Sun Aug 09 2015 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)

For '1420100000000' we get.

Local:
Ok: Thu, 01 Jan 2015 08:13:20 GMT - UTC
Ok: Thu Jan 01 2015 09:13:20 GMT+0100

Remote:
Ok: Thu, 01 Jan 2015 08:13:20 GMT - UTC
Ok: Thu Jan 01 2015 08:13:20 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)

I have a feeling the problem has something to do with the time being set to 00:00:00 on the server and then losing an hour when converted on the client taking the time 1 hour before midnight and thus the previous day.

This is why I went to UTC but the UTC dates still take the time back 1 hour. In the DB they are 2015-08-10 <-- 10th Aug not the 9th Aug. On both server/client the UTC date comes back as 9th Aug. Why is the server dropping a day and is there a way I can fix this? I am seeing the same problem with a basic javascript test harness and all my jtables.

Here is my harness code:-

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

    var dt_error = '1439157600000'; 
    var dt_ok = '1420100000000';        

    var pIntDateError = parseInt(dt_error,10);
    var pIntDateOk = parseInt(dt_ok,10);

    var dateUTC_error = new Date(pIntDateError).toUTCString();
    var dateUTC_ok = new Date(pIntDateOk).toUTCString();

    var date_error = new Date(pIntDateError);
    var date_ok = new Date(pIntDateOk);

    document.write('<div>Error: '+dateUTC_error+' - UTC</div>');
    document.write('<div>Error: '+date_error+'</div><br/>');
    document.write('<div>Ok: '+dateUTC_ok+' - UTC</div>');      
    document.write('<div>Ok: '+date_ok+'</div>');

    }
</script>
```

Thanks again for your time!

Br

Comment: I'd like to help but the problem isn't clear to me. Could you summarize somewhere: what is the expected behavior vs. the actual behavior and on what machine does this mismatch happen? (server, db or client)

Comment: Hi Teo, thanks for the heads up!

I dug deeper and see the problem but I am not sure how to fix it.

I'm using jquery datepicker to put a day/month/year into a database on a remote server. Sadly, the date gets normalised with hours/mins/sec all set too 0. The javascript Date function parses the year/month/day inclusive of the hours mins and secs and corrects for the current local. 

I need the JavaScript Data function to ignore the hours, minutes and seconds so that it does not correct for local and thus just returns the day/month/year without correction.  

Hope this is clearer?

Comment: Cont..

By correcting for he local the date is being taken back by 1 hour (I'm GMT and the sever is located +1 with respect to GMT) and taking the date back to the previous day. Not the desire effect. I need the exact day as shown in the DB to appear as is on every server regardless of local.

Br

Comment: I don't understand the problem from the logical point of view. You have some times in UTC which you store in the database. Then based on those times you create Date objects in Javascript. But the Date object has 2 sets of methods (e.g. getHours() vs. getUTCHours()  - the first will give you the hour in local time, the second will give you the hour in UTC). http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp So it's a matter of choice whether you want to display UTC or local time.

Comment: Hi Teo, 

The only date I want displayed in my jtable and datepicker is the un-corrected DB date. That is the DB shows 1/1/2015 I want 1/1/2015 in the jtable and calendar regardless of the region the client is located in! and for the life in me I cannot seem to figure it out other then going away from using date methods. The date is always corrected regardless of method used.

That's about as clear as I can make it. Hopefully you now understand my problem?

Br

Comment: My hunch is somewhere in your architecture you might have a wrong expectation - but i wrote this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9n86fyg/ It takes the following time: http://currentmillis.com/?1439768597692 As you can see that's a time just before midnight in UTC so for most (if not all) countries to the east of the Greenwich meridian the date would be 1 + the date in the Greenwich meridian. The fiddle contains all the possibilities for decoding/displaying dates in both original client timezone as well as UTC. Isn't what you want included among those method calls?

Comment: In case you yourself are in UTC here is my current output from that fiddle: LOCAL TIME: Mon Aug 17 2015 02:43:17 GMT+0300 (GTB Summer Time) - 
LOCAL DATE: 17 - UTC TIME: Sun, 16 Aug 2015 23:43:17 GMT - UTC DATE: 16 - Notice the 16 vs 17 difference (but also notice that the times are equal)